# Filter div when select option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a page with different locations with different prices. When selecting an option the div is filtered with the value attribute. I have multiple select options. I want to filter the divs with location AND also ascending prices should be visible. Any other suggestions to filter with locations are also welcome.

```js
$('select').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

  $this.addClass('select-hidden');
  $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
  $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

  var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
  $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

  var $list = $('<ul />', {
    'class': 'select-options'
  }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
    $('<li />', {
      text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
      rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
    }).appendTo($list);
  }

  var $listItems = $list.children('li');

  $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
  });

  $listItems.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide();
    //console.log($this.val());
  });

  $(document).click(function() {
    $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
    $list.hide();
  });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".col-lg-4 ").not("." + optionValue).hide();
        $("." + optionValue).show();
      } else {
        $(".col-lg-4 ").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="sale_property" class="response">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <form>
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
            <li class="active"><a href="#buy" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Buy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#rent" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Rent / PG</a></li>
            <li><a href="#plot" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="responsive">Plot</a></li>
            <li><a href="#commercial" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="responsive">Commercial</a></li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Tab panes -->
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="buy">
              <div class="form-search">

                <div class="custom-select-wrapper">
                  <select>
                    <option value="hide" disable>-- Select Location --</option>
                    <option value="gulmohar">Gulmohar Colony, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="govind">Govind Nagar, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="makhbalabad">Makhbalabad Road, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="mhasrul">Mhasrul, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="pathardi">Pathardi Phata, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="konarch">Konark Nagar, Nashik</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="arrow type-property"></div>
                </div>
                <select>
                  <option value="hide" disable>-- Budget --</option>
                  <option value="lac5">5Lac</option>
                  <option value="lac10">10Lac</option>
                  <option value="lac15">15Lac</option>
                  <option value="lac20">20Lac</option>
                  <option value="lac25">25Lac</option>
                  <option value="lac30">30Lac</option>
                  <option value="lac35">35Lac</option>
                  <option value="lac40">40Lac</option>
                  <option value="Above">Above 40Lac</option>
                </select>
                <div class="arrow type-property"></div>
                <select>
                  <option value="hide" disable>-- Property Type --</option>
                  <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
                  <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
                  <option value="Others">Others</option>
                </select>
                <div class="arrow type-property"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="rent">
              <div class="form-search">
                <div class="custom-select-wrapper">
                  <select>
                    <option value="hide" disable>-- Select Location --</option>
                    <option value="gulmohar">Gulmohar Colony, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="govind">Govind Nagar, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="makhbalabad">Makhbalabad Road, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="mhasrul">Mhasrul, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="pathardi">Pathardi Phata, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="konarch">Konark Nagar, Nashik</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="arrow type-property"></div>
                </div>
                <select>
                  <option value="hide" disable>-- Budget --</option>
                  <option value="5Lac">5Lac</option>
                  <option value="10Lac">10Lac</option>
                  <option value="15Lac">15Lac</option>
                  <option value="20Lac">20Lac</option>
                  <option value="25Lac">25Lac</option>
                  <option value="30Lac">30Lac</option>
                  <option value="35Lac">35Lac</option>
                  <option value="40Lac">40Lac</option>
                  <option value="Above">Above 40Lac</option>
                </select>
                <div class="arrow type-property"></div>
                <select>
                  <option value="hide" disable>-- Property Type --</option>
                  <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
                  <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
                  <option value="Others">Others</option>
                </select>
                <div class="arrow type-property"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="plot">
              <div class="form-search">
                <div class="custom-select-wrapper">
                  <select>
                    <option value="hide" disable>-- Select Location --</option>
                    <option value="gulmohar">Gulmohar Colony, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="govind">Govind Nagar, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="makhbalabad">Makhbalabad Road, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="mhasrul">Mhasrul, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="pathardi">Pathardi Phata, Nashik</option>
                    <option value="konarch">Konark Nagar, Nashik</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="arrow type-property"></div>
                </div>
                <select>
                  <option value="hide" disable>-- Budget --</option>
                  <option value="5Lac">5Lac</option>
                  <option value="10Lac">10Lac</option>
                  <option value="15Lac">15Lac</option>
                  <option value="20Lac">20Lac</option>
                  <option value="25Lac">25Lac</option>
                  <option value="30Lac">30Lac</option>
                  <option value="35Lac">35Lac</option>
                  <option value="40Lac">40Lac</option>
                  <option value="Above">Above 40Lac</option>
                </select>
                <div class="arrow type-property"></div>
                <select>
                  <option value="hide" disable>-- Property Type --</option>
                  <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
                  <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
                  <option value="Others">Others</option>
                </select>
                <div class="arrow type-property"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>

</section>

<section id="property-gallery">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <h1>Project Gallery</h1>
        <div class="col-lg-4 makhbalabad lac40">
            <div class="property-box">
                <div class="property-img">
                    <img src="imgs/gallery/1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <span class="offer-gallery">Nashik</span>
                </div>
                <div class="property-text">
                        <h2>Icon Construction</h2>
                        <p>Makhmalabad, Behind Shantinagar
Bus Stop, Makhmalabad Road, Nashik.</p>
                        <span>2 BHK Flats</span>
                    
                        <h3 class="price">&#8377; 39 Lac</h3>
                        <p class="onward">Onwards</p>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">See Details</a>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 lac20 mhasrul ">
            <div class="property-box">
                <div class="property-img">
                    <img src="imgs/gallery/2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <span class="offer-gallery">Nashik</span>
                </div>
                <div class="property-text">
                        <h2>Dreamnano residency</h2>
                        <p>Pushpak Nagar, Near Puspavinayak Temple, Mhasrul, Nashik.</p>
                        <span>1 BHK Flats</span>
                    
                        <h3 class="price">&#8377; 17.5 Lac</h3>
                        <p class="onward">Onwards</p>
                        <a href="#">See Details</a>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 mhasrul above">
            <div class=" property-box">
                <div class="property-img">
                    <img src="imgs/gallery/3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <span class="offer-gallery">Nashik</span>
                </div>
                <div class="property-text">
                        <h2>Icon Construction</h2>
                        <p>Aadarsh row Bunglow, Aadarsh Nagar, NEAR 
A.T.PAWAR ASHRAM SCHOOL, BORGAD, MHASRUL, NASHIK.</p>
                        <span>2 BHK Flats</span>
                    
                        <h3 class="price">&#8377; 55 Lac</h3>
                        <p class="onward">Onwards</p>
                        <a href="#">See Details</a>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 konark lac25 ">
            <div class="property-box">
                <div class="property-img">
                    <img src="imgs/gallery/4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <span class="offer-gallery">Nashik</span>
                </div>
                <div class="property-text">
                        <h2>Home for Sale</h2>
                        <p>Sakarpuja Apartment, Near Panchkrushn Lawn,
Konark Nagar, Near Jatra Hotel, Nashik.</p>
                        <span>2 BHK Flats</span>
                    
                        <h3 class="price">&#8377; 25 Lac</h3>
                        <p class="onward">Onwards</p>
                        <a href="#">See Details</a>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="makhbalabad col-lg-4 lac30 lac25 ">
            <div class="property-box">
                <div class="property-img">
                    <img src="imgs/gallery/5.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <span class="offer-gallery">Nashik</span>
                </div>
                <div class="property-text">
                        <h2>Home for Resale </h2>
                        <p>Gokuldham Soc.
Behind Sharad Pawar Market Yard, Peth Road, Makhmalabad, Nashik.</p>
                        <span>2 BHK Flats</span>
                    
                        <h3 class="price">&#8377; 27 Lac</h3>
                        <p class="onward">Onwards</p>
                        <a href="#">See Details</a>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 mhasrul above ">
            <div class="property-box">
                <div class="property-img">
                    <img src="imgs/gallery/3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <span class="offer-gallery">Nashik</span>
                </div>
                <div class="property-text">
                        <h2>Icon Construction</h2>
                        <p>Aadarsh row Bunglow, Aadarsh Nagar, NEAR 
A.T.PAWAR ASHRAM SCHOOL, BORGAD, MHASRUL, NASHIK.</p>
                        <span>2 BHK Flats</span>
                    
                        <h3 class="price">&#8377; 55 Lac</h3>
                        <p class="onward">Onwards</p>
                        <a href="#">See Details</a>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
      
        
        
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi where is divs which you need to filter ?

Comment: Hi, I have added property-gallery section. Need to filter the data inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve above one way would be storing value of selects in array as key-value pair because there multiple such select-boxes .

In below code i have first loop through all selects which are there under `tab-pane` then i have use 2 array one to store *key-value* i.e : if *data-value="location"* and *value="makhbalabad"* so key will be location and value will be makhbalabad and the other to store only keys i.e : location,price..etc.

Now , once we get all value from the selects we need to loop through **Project Gallery** divs  .Then i have check if the value in array has class inside your div i.e : `col-lg-4` if yes we can use some variable to store count and depending on this we will show or hide that divs .You can do same for other `tab` as well only add `data-value` in your select-boxes

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".col-lg-4").show();
$("select").change(function() {
  var arrSelected = [];
  var arrTypes = [];
  //loop through all selects inside a particular tab only
  $(this).closest(".tab-pane").find("select").each(function() {

    //check if value is undefined
    if (arrSelected[$(this).attr('data-value')] == undefined) {
      arrSelected[$(this).attr('data-value')] = [];
    }
    //add value in key value pair
    arrSelected[$(this).attr('data-value')].push($(this).val());
    //push key value in arry
    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('data-value'), arrTypes) < 0) {
      arrTypes.push($(this).attr('data-value')); //add key  to another array
    }

  })
  $(".col-lg-4").hide(); //hide all 
  //loop through divs
  $('.col-lg-4').each(function() {
    var intKeyCount = 0;
    //get keys of selcts
    for (key in arrTypes) {
      var blnFound = false;
      //get value at that keys
      for (val in arrSelected[arrTypes[key]]) {
        //check if the data attr matchs with class  or if value is hide
        if ($(this).hasClass(arrSelected[arrTypes[key]][val]) || (arrSelected[arrTypes[key]][val] == "hide")) {
          blnFound = true; //we found 
          break;
        }
      }
      if (blnFound) {
        intKeyCount++; //increment value 
      }
    }
    //check if it matches atleast one -filter or if you need to match all condition then use both 
    if ((intKeyCount > 0) && (intKeyCount == arrTypes.length)) {
      $(this).show(); //show
    } else {
      $(this).hide(); //hide
    }

  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-pane active" id="buy">
  <div class="form-search">

    <div class="custom-select-wrapper">
      <!--added datta atrr-->
      <select data-value="location">
        <option value="hide" disable>-- Select Location --</option>
        <option value="gulmohar">Gulmohar Colony, Nashik</option>
        <option value="govind">Govind Nagar, Nashik</option>
        <option value="makhbalabad">Makhbalabad Road, Nashik</option>
        <option value="mhasrul">Mhasrul, Nashik</option>
        <option value="pathardi">Pathardi Phata, Nashik</option>
        <option value="konarch">Konark Nagar, Nashik</option>
      </select>
      <div class="arrow type-property"></div>
    </div>
    <!--added datta atrr-->
    <select data-value="price">
      <option value="hide" disable>-- Budget --</option>
      <option value="lac5">5Lac</option>
      <option value="lac10">10Lac</option>
      <option value="lac15">15Lac</option>
      <option value="lac20">20Lac</option>
      <option value="lac25">25Lac</option>
      <option value="lac30">30Lac</option>
      <option value="lac35">35Lac</option>
      <option value="lac40">40Lac</option>
      <option value="above">Above 40Lac</option>
    </select>
    <div class="arrow type-property"></div>
    <!--added datta atrr-->
    <select data-value="property">
      <option value="hide" disable>-- Property Type --</option>
      <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
      <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
      <option value="Others">Others</option>
    </select>
    <div class="arrow type-property"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<section id="property-gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Project Gallery</h1>
      <div class="col-lg-4 makhbalabad lac40">
        <div class="property-box">
          <div class="property-img">
            <img src="imgs/gallery/1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <span class="offer-gallery">Nashik</span>
          </div>
          <div class="property-text">
            <h2>Icon Construction</h2>
            <p>Makhmalabad, Behind Shantinagar Bus Stop, Makhmalabad Road, Nashik.</p>
            <span>2 BHK Flats</span>

            <h3 class="price">&#8377; 39 Lac</h3>
            <p class="onward">Onwards</p>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">See Details</a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 lac20 mhasrul ">
        <div class="property-box">
          <div class="property-img">
            <img src="imgs/gallery/2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <span class="offer-gallery">Nashik</span>
          </div>
          <div class="property-text">
            <h2>Dreamnano residency</h2>
            <p>Pushpak Nagar, Near Puspavinayak Temple, Mhasrul, Nashik.</p>
            <span>1 BHK Flats</span>

            <h3 class="price">&#8377; 17.5 Lac</h3>
            <p class="onward">Onwards</p>
            <a href="#">See Details</a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 mhasrul above">
        <div class=" property-box">
          <div class="property-img">
            <img src="imgs/gallery/3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <span class="offer-gallery">Nashik</span>
          </div>
          <div class="property-text">
            <h2>Icon Construction</h2>
            <p>Aadarsh row Bunglow, Aadarsh Nagar, NEAR A.T.PAWAR ASHRAM SCHOOL, BORGAD, MHASRUL, NASHIK.</p>
            <span>2 BHK Flats</span>

            <h3 class="price">&#8377; 55 Lac</h3>
            <p class="onward">Onwards</p>
            <a href="#">See Details</a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 konark lac25 ">
        <div class="property-box">
          <div class="property-img">
            <img src="imgs/gallery/4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <span class="offer-gallery">Nashik</span>
          </div>
          <div class="property-text">
            <h2>Home for Sale</h2>
            <p>Sakarpuja Apartment, Near Panchkrushn Lawn, Konark Nagar, Near Jatra Hotel, Nashik.</p>
            <span>2 BHK Flats</span>

            <h3 class="price">&#8377; 25 Lac</h3>
            <p class="onward">Onwards</p>
            <a href="#">See Details</a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="makhbalabad col-lg-4 lac30 lac25 ">
        <div class="property-box">
          <div class="property-img">
            <img src="imgs/gallery/5.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <span class="offer-gallery">Nashik</span>
          </div>
          <div class="property-text">
            <h2>Home for Resale </h2>
            <p>Gokuldham Soc. Behind Sharad Pawar Market Yard, Peth Road, Makhmalabad, Nashik.</p>
            <span>2 BHK Flats</span>

            <h3 class="price">&#8377; 27 Lac</h3>
            <p class="onward">Onwards</p>
            <a href="#">See Details</a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 mhasrul above ">
        <div class="property-box">
          <div class="property-img">
            <img src="imgs/gallery/3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <span class="offer-gallery">Nashik</span>
          </div>
          <div class="property-text">
            <h2>Icon Construction</h2>
            <p>Aadarsh row Bunglow, Aadarsh Nagar, NEAR A.T.PAWAR ASHRAM SCHOOL, BORGAD, MHASRUL, NASHIK.</p>
            <span>2 BHK Flats</span>

            <h3 class="price">&#8377; 55 Lac</h3>
            <p class="onward">Onwards</p>
            <a href="#">See Details</a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>





    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This worked for me but when I select options from --select Location -- and reselect -- select Location -- no div is visible

Comment: Hi i have updated my code ..have a look let me know if that doesn't work now also :)